# Kibana+nginx reverse_proxy issue

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, proxypass, kibana

*Greetings!*

I had to face issue with NginX `reverse_proxy` and Kibana. If I make Kibana index - nothing shows until I clear browser cache or visit page from Private Tab in browser. Here is my `server.conf` (without server {})

```
include default_proxy_headers;
set $upstream_prod_kibana_registry http://prod_kibana:5601;
resolver 127.0.0.11 ipv6=off valid=10s;
listen 80;
listen 443 ssl http2;
listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
server_name kibana.my.domain;
auth_basic "Restricted";
auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/htpasswd;
location / {
    proxy_buffering off;
    proxy_pass $upstream_prod_kibana_registry;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Connection "Keep-Alive";
    proxy_set_header Proxy-Connection "Keep-Alive";
}
```

But if I visit Kibana's page directly with port http://kibana.my.domain:5601 - everything is here, no need to clear cache.
I think it's nginx problem. What should I do?

Comment: Check HTTP headers returned in both cases: `curl -i http://kibana.my.domain:5601/ -o /dev/null` and `curl -i https://kibana.my.domain/ -o /dev/null`. Show both commands output.

Comment: I added `add_header Cache-Control "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate";` and this worked for me.